# SqlQuestion how to convert dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt as dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have column name abcd as `varchar` in that I am inserting the datetime as
`dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`

So when I am selecting that date time filed I want to display date time as
`dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`
simply

Comment: Why are you storing `datetime` in a `varchar` column in the first place?

Comment: am using anothers person  datatable so i want use that table

Comment: am not design that table it is design by another one just i want use that

Answer (score 0):

if that column is varchar, you can just use replace function to replace '/' to '-'.

```sql
select replace(abcd, '/', '-') newdates from table
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the DATEFORMAT here first, if you want to convert the varchar into a proper date, otherwise it'd fail.

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
-- then you can convert the string to a datetime
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, abcd);
```

Then you can output as you wish in all the supported formats for SQL Server - see "Date and Time styles" on this link : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx